# sbt plugin that depends on itself to build itself

Tags: sbt

How can I make an sbt plugin whose build definition has a dependency on code written in the plugin itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because sbt is recursive, this is simple. Create or edit `project/build.sbt`, and add

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += new File("src/main/scala")
```

Answer (score 1):

the old answer no longer works. 
Need a small tweak, add `getAbsoluteFile` at the end:

```
    unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += file("src/main/scala").getAbsoluteFile
```